# Get rid of goto statement from embedded C/C++ logic

Tags: c++, c

I want to get rid of this `goto` statement. Can any one tell me the logic for the same. The code below is not the exact code that I want to modify, but it will support my question. Please don't ask the significance of the code when commenting on this post as it is just an example.

```
int result[i][j];
for (int i = 0; i<100; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j<100; j++)
    {
        result[i][j] = j++;
        if (j == 80)
            goto break1;
    }
}
break1:
…;
```

Comment: please pick a language, C and C++ have different idioms and different solutions

Comment: goto is not necessarily evil.  in a complex flow control loop it might be the most efficient way.

Comment: using a variable which can be asked at every loop level is a often found solution. In *my* opinion, a goto is much clearer to do what it should do: leave the loop! The first thing which should be done is to simplify the nested loops, but if this is also not a useful way, please stay with a simple, easy to understand and clear goto!

Comment: In this example, you can change the inner loop to `for (j = 0; j < 80; j++)`.  What's the more general version of the problem?  Could it be `if (j == function(i, j)) goto break1;`?  If so, then the `goto` is reasonable.  Else you have to use a flag and a `break` statement.  (Incidentally, `goto` is not a 'call'; it is a statement.)

Comment: Presumably `int result[i][j];` should be `int result[100][100];`

Comment: Humor: This is obviously a good use case for longjmp()

Comment: goto is not MISRA favourable ....

Comment: `result[i][j] = j++;` invokes undefined behaviour anyway ;-)

Comment: @chqrlie Of course, and the `goto` is never reached anyway. I just hoped his real code does not do that. :)

Comment: It is or it isn't, or both at the same time!  The beauty of undefined behaviour.

Comment: If you are allowed to modify `i` and `j` within the loops, you could write something horrible like `{ i = j = 100; }` or `{ i = 100; break; }`.  But it is an evil fix.

Answer (score 4):

Put those loops in a function, give it a proper name and `return;` when it is done. If it is complicated enough to need two loops, it deserves a name.

A finished flag is so hard to read that you should put that construct in its own function anyway, making it obsolete.

Exceptions are only for errors you cannot handle locally. Use them to notify higher level functions that something you cannot fix went wrong, not if something that was supposed to happen happened.

Comment: MISRA would not condone an embedded `return` statement either.  They would favor a finished flag.  I agree with you that it would be a horrible solution, the fix is worse than the problem

Comment: @chqrlie I do not know MISRA, but if it favors the flag over a function, it sure is stupid IMO. What kind of system does not support `return` statements?

Comment: They insist that there be a single `return` statement at the end of the function body.

Answer (score 2):

I would see three possible solutions.

1. Put the code into a function and leave that function with `return`
2. Use a "finished" flag like already demonstrated well in the answers by Michel Keijzers, Bas in het Feld and EvilTeach.
3. (C++ only) surround the code-section with a try-catch-block and throw and exception when you want to leave the code. But keep in mind that exceptions are usually supposed to be used for error-handling. So you should only use this pattern when terminating the loops is the result of an error conditions.

Comment: An exception? Really?

Comment: OP asks for embedded code. Often embedded systems have exceptions and RTTI switched off. And I believe that an exception should not be used to handle *normal* abort conditions.

Comment: using an exception for this is even higher on the evil scale!

Comment: An exception should only be used for ... exceptions, and in this case it seems (or might be) that something has been found which is not an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Use a boolean to break from the for loop(s).

```
int result[i][j];
bool cont = 1;
for (int i =0;i<100;i++)
{
    for(j = 0;j<100;j++)
    {
        result[i][j] = j++;
        if(j == 80)
        {
            cont = 0;            
            break; 
        }
    }
    if (cont == 0)
        break;
}
break1;
```

(note: not tested on real compiler).

Comment: The code with goto was easy to read for me. If your change is the solution, I want back my problem :-)

Comment: This will fail if there is a `continue` in the real code.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to break two loops, you have to notify the outer loop. You can do this by having a boolean that checks for that:

```
bool break_loop = false;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; ++j) {
        if (j == 80) {
            break_loop = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (break_loop) break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int result[i][j];
for (int i = 0; i<100; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j<100; j++)
    {
        result[i][j] = j++;
        if (j == 80)
        {
           i = 100;
           break;
        }
    }
}
```

The break statement breaks out of the inner loop.
Setting i to 100, causes the outer loop to finish.

Comment: is break statement is misra compilable ??

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes like changing the control variable(s)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
        /* work */
        if (j == 80) i = j = 100; // 100 makes both loops terminate
    }
}
```

Comment: We have seen now a dozen of solutions to fight against goto. And as I believe, the goto was in all cases even better than all the code presented in the "solutions" here. "Goto is bad" can result in worse code as we can see. On work we have coding rules which disallow the modification of control/loop vars inside the loop itself. And I think this is as bad as goto.

Answer (score 0):

```
int result[i][j];
for (int i = 0; i<100; i++)
{
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j<100; j++)
    {
        result[i][j] = j++;
        if (j == 80)break;
    }
    if(j == 80) break;
}
```

Know this is an old question but can be modified simply